# Issues removing a Block from content

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm working on an old D7 site and have been asked to remove a Block from a particular page.

First thing I tried was to go to the page in question, click the gear icon next to the block and select Configure Block. I then added the page's alias to the list of excluded pages (ie: "All pages except those listed").

I saved, cleared cache, but this had no affect - the block remains on the page.

I then went to see if I could remove the Block from its region, so I went to `admin/structure/block/` and found my Block - but the thing is it's unassigned. It's in the Disabled category.

Would anyone know what's going on here and how I can remove the block from just one given alias?

Comment: The block is probably included by other means than the usual block region display. Maybe there is panels, or the block is programatically inserted or some other module.

Comment: Find out how this block got placed on the page then we can tell you how to remove it. Check nodes body fields or block reference fields, check nested views, check custom modules, check custom templates, check Display Suite or Contexts, could be many places, this still isn't the full list.

Comment: Are you sure have the radio button clicked that is labeled `All pages except those listed`? Can you use the original path (node/[number]) instead of the alias? When you go to the Blocks page you have to pay attention under which theme you're looking! Different themes have Blocks config available as sub-tabs pages.